# Describing a dropped phone call

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, past-tense, grammaticality-in-context, sequence-of-tenses

What can I say to describe a dropped phone call:

1- The phone call just dropped.

2- The phone call just cut out.

3- The phone call just disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

All three of your examples are acceptable and understood by most English speakers. Although “cut out” could mean that you lost connection only momentarily. The call is still connected. But, you missed some words.